# Get Images In Directory and Subdirectory With Glob

Tags: php

I have a PHP script written to grab all images in a certain directory and display them, although I want to have the ability to display images also in sub directories of the directory I specified.

So for example right now my script is only getting the following images

**uploads/prevImgs/145323.png**

**uploads/prevImgs/276531.png**

Where id want it to get the following

**uploads/prevImgs/145323.png**

**uploads/prevImgs/276531.png**

**uploads/prevImgs/dir1/12323.png**

**uploads/prevImgs/dir2/212331.png**

My current script is the following

```
<?php
  // Directory Path Of Library Preview Images //
  $dirname = "uploads/prevImgs/";
  $images = glob("{$dirname}*.*");
  foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
  }
?>
```

> **Huge thanks in advance!!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stack a RecursiveDirectoryIterator and an RecursiveIteratorIterator to get the effect you're looking for:

```
$rdi = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("uploads/prevImgs/");
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($rdi);
foreach($it as $oneThing)
    if (is_file($oneThing))
        echo '<img src="'.$oneThing.'" /><br />';
```

I know, it seems counter-intuitive that you have to take RecursiveDirectoryIterator and stack **another** iterator on top of it to make it work.  The documentation in this area could be better.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest to use a RecursiveDirectoryIterator for creating a class to iterate through Files of (sub)directories and its files. Together with one of the recursive filter iterators php offers you can only return only image files.

There is a GlobIterator too but I'm not sure if it also do recursive iterations.