# PHP Create Image Gallery From Directory And Subdirectories

Tags: php

I'm trying to make an image gallery that scans a main directory and creates a separate album for each subdirectory.

My structure is similar to this:

-Gallery
--Subdir 1
---Image 1
---Image 2
--Subdir 2
---Image 1
---Image 2

The idea is that each album is going to be made of a div with a class of `web-gallery`. Then there will be a header for the album title made from the subdirectories name. After that a list is generated of each image. This is going to be a one page gallery. If possible I would like to have a variable that sets how many albums are listed that way if I have 30 subdirectories my page doesn't get too crowded.

So far I've written this but it doesn't work. I'm not getting any errors or logs though it just doesn't work.

```
$dirs = glob('img/gallery_temp/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
   foreach($dirs as $val) {
  echo '<div class="web-gallery">';
  echo "<h3><span>&raquo;</span> ".basename($val). "</h3>"; 
  echo '<ul class="web-gallery-list">';
 $files = glob($val.'*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
 foreach($files as $file) {
 echo "<li><a href='".$file."'><img src='" . $file . "' alt='description'></a></li> \r\n";
 }
echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't a very clear description of the problem. Can you be more specific?

Comment: It does nothing at all. Nothing is written from the echo. No errors and my error reporting is on. And nothing is being logged in errors either.

Comment: output the `var_dump($dirs);` or may be the path specified in glob is wrong

Comment: Path was wrong. But when I fixed it the result was each subdirectories name was being listed as a header element but no images have resulted

Comment: I think it is not returning files because you didn't add a `/` (slash) before `*.{jpg,png,gif}`. I think `$val` doesn't have that final slash (this is just a guess).

Comment: Added the slash. No change

Comment: I take that back. I added the slash in the wrong place. If you can put that as an answer I'll accept. Thanks guys.

Comment: @JesseElser You are very welcome! I am glad I could also help alongside Tamil. I added the answer, but it's ok if you don't accept it, I just want to help and I'm good with that. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a `/` before `*.{jpg,png,gif}` like this:

```
$files = glob($val.'/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

This is because `$val` doesn't have a final `/` for the directory.

Comment: Accepted since this fixed my initial problem

Comment: @JesseElser Great! I repeat again I am glad I could help even with the very tiniest detail. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using "readdir" instead of glob. Glob is to find pathnames matching a pattern, see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php and is known to be a bit problematic.

Readdir, if your directory is entirely images might be easier to use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Couple this with is_dir() http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php to resolve your directories vs files.  Here is a snippet

```
<?php
    if ($handle = opendir('/galleries')) {
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

            // this is a subdirectory
            if (is_dir($entry)) {

            }
            // this is a file
            else {
                echo $entry;
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
?>
```

If you make it a recursive function you could actually have it traverse a number of subdirectories creating galleries within galleries.

I also found this fantastic little snippet that is very elegant on another stack question:  [Get Images In Directory and Subdirectory With Glob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585670/get-images-in-directory-and-subdirectory-with-glob?rq=1)

```
$rdi = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("uploads/prevImgs/");
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($rdi);
foreach($it as $oneThing)
    if (is_file($oneThing))
        echo '<img src="'.$oneThing.'" /><br />';
```

Comment: Kinda new to php I'm not sure how to work that into my current script.

Answer (score 1):

**Using SPL Library** (PHP >= 5)

Better solution in your case
is to use SPL library (the most cross-platform)

```
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("./img/gallery_temp", FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
// Flatten the recursive iterator, folders come before their files
$it  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($it as $fileinfo)
{
    if($fileinfo->isDir())
    {
        // prevPath used to separate each directory listing and closing the bracket UL list
        $prevPath = $it->getSubPath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$fileinfo->getFilename();
        echo sprintf
        (
            "<div class='web-gallery'>
            <h3><span>></span> %s</h3>
            <ul>".PHP_EOL,
            $fileinfo->getFilename()
        );
    }

    if($fileinfo->isFile())
    {
        echo sprintf("<li><a href=''><img src='%s/%s' alt='description'></a></li>".PHP_EOL,  $it->getSubPath(), $fileinfo->getFilename());
        if($prevPath != $it->getSubPath())
            echo("</ul>");
    }
}
```

Note: 
For more informations : [SPL Documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.spl.php)

- **DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR** is a cross-platform constant, will use the
  correct directory separator of the OS where are executed the code
- **FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS**, avoid to fetch the '.' and '..' dir
  link level.
- you can limit the depth of scanning with $it->setMaxDepth(5);

Comment: Is this a built in library or third.party I have to implement?

Comment: SPL (Standard PHP Library) Look here : http://php.net/manual/en/spl.installation.php, 
It's not a native library, it's a PHP extension fully integrated (at the compilation of php) since PHP 5 (that why is often considered as native..)

It will work as well, if you are on php >= 5
Nothing is required !