# How can I display all images and videos in a folder and subfolders ordered by date (newer on top)?

Tags: php, image, date

Using PHP, I'm trying to display all images in a folder and subfolders, ordered by date (newer on top).

A [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585670/get-images-in-directory-and-subdirectory-with-glob?rq=1#_=_) from [@slashingweapon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292052/slashingweapon) worked perfectly. But I just can't make it display the images ordered by date.

I'm trying "filemtime" but can't make it work (I'm not a programmer, just a diy person).

I'll be glad if someone could give some advice.

Thank you!

```
<?php
$rdi = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("uploads/prevImgs/");
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($rdi);
foreach($it as $oneThing)
    if (is_file($oneThing))
        echo '<img src="'.$oneThing.'" /><br />';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort the values by modified time, you need to read them into an array and then sort that before displaying them. To deal with files possibly having the same `mtime` we use a multi-dimensional array which is then sorted using the `mtime` column using [`array_multisort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php). We add the required output to the array so that you can ehco those values directly for easier output:

```
$rdi = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("uploads/prevImgs/");
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($rdi);
$files = array();
foreach($it as $oneThing) {
    if (is_file($oneThing)) {
        $files[] = array('mtime' => filemtime($oneThing), 'image' => '<img src="'.$oneThing.'" /><br />');
    }
}
array_multisort(array_column($files, 'mtime'), $files);
echo implode(array_column($files, 'image'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I couldn't make it work. It has no errors, but the place where images should appear is blank. The menu appears, the Chrome inspector shows no erros. Replacing $files[filemtime[$image]] = by echo displays the images, but not sorting by date.

Comment: @gisz sorry I had a typo, used `[]` instead of `()` for the call to `filemtime`...

Comment: Wow, you're awesome! But something weird happened, because it is not opening all images. Don't understand why, maybe because there are images with the same timestamp.

Comment: @gisz yes, that would be an issue. See my edit, if that is the issue it should resolve that.

Comment: CORRECTION! It DID work! I'm seriously believing you're a genius ("multi-dimensional array" is amazingly insane to me). I do appreciate all your help!!! Thank you very much, @Nick, you're amazing!

Comment: @gisz good to hear.